# 999.99 Value for 1138 In Mysql/PhP My Admin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am very new to php and mysql so sorry if this is a silly question,

I am importing some measurement data into the database via PhP My Admin.

The CSV has values going from 1 to 3000, some have decimals and some don't.

Due to this I don't think the table likes the mix up.

Most of the values show correctly, apart from when the values go over 999, one of the measurement values shows 999.99 for a value of 1138.

Is there any way to stop it doing this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can you show us your table schema ?

Comment: Most likely, your column is `DECIMAL(5,2)` thus can't fit the value and MySQL is not configured to trigger errors on that.

Comment: What does table schema mean? Sorry...

Comment: It is set to decimal 5,2 also

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's the problem, data type. As per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.6 are as follows:
>
> **M is the maximum number of digits** (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> **D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point** (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

So your `DECIMAL(5,2)` column type can hold numbers up to `999.99`. You'll have to alter the table and make the column larger.

(As about why MySQL prefers to corrupt your data rather than reporting it, well, that's been its philosophy from the early years. You can play with [SQL modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-sql-modes.html) to fix that.)

Comment: Is there any easy way of doing this? As i'm not an expert with my Sql and don't want to break anything?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean. You are asking a question about PhpMyAdmin: do you want an alternative to that?

Comment: Is there any way i can "make the column bigger" by using PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, of course—it's like asking whether you can use Firefox to browse the web xD But I'm not a PhpMyAdmin user myself so I can't tell you what label the menu has. But you should be able to find it yourself.