# MYSQL DECIMAL(5,2) returns 999.99 instead of the input value (82.50)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, decimal

## MYSQL 5.5 / PHP plugin to WordPress, using HTML forms for input

This is similar to the problem mentioned in 
[999.99 Value for 1138 In Mysql/PhP My Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721517/999-99-value-for-1138-in-mysql-php-my-admin)
but NOT THE SAME!

The values my users need to enter in my online form will never be larger than 999.99 for this one field (column), so why is MYSQL giving me 999.99 when I enter 82.50 ? The error is not just in the frontend, on viewing the form - the form allows me to enter 82.50, but then displays 999.99, and this is the value in the DB column too.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Can you try create a new table with the same collumn type and add (via sql insert) this value to check if the problem persist? I think the problem could be  the value that is being sent... Maybe something is removing the dot before insert the data in your table.

Comment: Thanks - will try this, although it means changing my code in the plugin as well, which is quite a job. Good idea though.

Comment: No need to. If you have the rights, you can access your database (via sql server, phpMyadmin, Workbench, or whatever) and run the sql queries. One for create a new table test with that kind of column and another query making an insert in that table.

Comment: I was asking this because i made a test here in my localhost and it saved with no problems (82.50). So, unless we can prove your database have some configuration that makes this value changes ( we can prove it by doing this test in your database), it's probably something with the application that is sending the data wrong.

Comment: Please show the relevant code -- input stuff, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT`, etc.  And is this in English locale? -- where decimal point is `.`?

Comment: Thanks to both of you - it works fine in the db itself. What I meant (but didn't explain very well) is that most of the PHP code is not mine, and this is clearly where the problem lies. I have been in touch with the dev guys, but as it's a question of MY addition to their plugin, they are not all that keen to help.

I will once again dig through all the object declarations and utility functions etc etc - believe me, there are a lot! - and if I find the solution I will post it here.